# add row and column to jTable in one loop

Tags: java, jtable, jform

I am working in NetBeans IDE, language Java, the main class is JFrameForm.

I have a jTable *tab* with just one row and one column, button and jTextField *en*, where type should be integers. The input is variable *n*.

I need to create matrix with *n* rows and *n* columns. So *n* x *n* dimension of matrix as a jTable.

After click on the button, variable *n* will be saved as dimension and loop will start add the column and row till *n*.

The code is following:

```
private void sendMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tab.getModel();

        String sn=en.getText();
        int n=Integer.valueOf(sn);

        for(int j=2;j<=n;j++){
            model.addColumn(null); // I know this is wrong
            model.addRow(new Object[]{test.getText()+j});
            test.setText(test.getText()+j);
        }
    }
```

I got error

*Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1*

The cells should be empty.

Please help me to input the column. What is object there?

Comment: Use a custom table model, that will be the best way.

Comment: What is `a` in the program? It seems as though you're trying to get an object mapped to an index greater than the length of the array, since `j` is supposed to be lower than the length maybe `a` is greater?

Comment: It was just mistake. I meant n

Comment: Could you give me the example of custom model? Link? I have heard about it for the first time (imma kind of beginner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set column names to JTable and then add rows in JTable..

```
private void sendMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    String sn=en.getText();
    int n=Integer.valueOf(sn);
    java.util.Vector columns = new java.util.Vector();
    columns.add("Your Column Name");
    java.util.Vector rows = new java.util.Vector();
    for(int j=2;j<=n;j++){
        java.util.Vector row = new java.util.Vector();
        row.add(test.getText()+j);
        rows.add(row);
        test.setText(test.getText()+j);
    }
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns);
    tab.setModel(model);
}
```

this will work..

Comment: with small edit work for column too.

`for(int j=2;j<=n;j++){
        
        java.util.Vector column = new java.util.Vector();
        column.add(test.getText()+j);
        columns.add(column);
        
        
        java.util.Vector row = new java.util.Vector();
        row.add(test.getText()+j);
        rows.add(row);
        
        test.setText(test.getText()+j);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I think (I didn't checked it) that your JTable tries to add a row but it doesn't have any column because of your `addColumn(null)`.

Why don't you just do `model.addColumn("");` with an empty string to add an empty cell ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can deduce, you want to use the variable `n`as an int. The `getText()` method will return the value as a string and the `valueOf()` method will return the string as a string. `valueOf()` is used for [the exact opposite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm) of what you want, converting an int for example into a string. You should use `Integer.parseInt()` instead outlined in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java). That will hopefully get rid of the out of bound exceptions.